# How to write test for user that doesn't exist in db? - Java, Spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I have a controller written in Java that I have to test

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{userId}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {

        Optional<UserUrl> userUrl = userUrlRepository.findById(UserId.userId(userId));
        return userUrl.map(uur -> uur.url )
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("user with id: %s doesn't exist", userId)));
    }
```

I would like to test exception case when user doesn't exist in database, but I am not sure how.

I started with this:

```
def "should throw an exception if user userId doesn't exist in database"(){
        when:
        mvc.perform(get("/get/{userId}", userId)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andDo(docConfig())
                .andReturn()
                .response
        
       then:
       1 * userUrlRepository.findById()

    }
```

How can I test this case?

Comment: Have you tried `1 * userUrlRepository.findById() >> Optional.empty()` ?

Comment: what is the response and status code returned when user is not found ?